# UIButtonType Delete constant

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Is there a constant for making a circle-delete button?

I want this button in my app:
[image: Delete button]

Must I custom create it or is there some constant such as `UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure` which I can use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry but it is not possible to create a button using the system's version of this. You will need to create a UIButton of type `UIButtonTypeCustom` and supply your own graphic (which you already have because you've added it above :-) ).

Comment: Also, don't forget to add an '@2x' version to support higher resolution devices.